# Full Calendar get cell attributes by date range

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

So I'm using Full Calendar JavaScript in my project. I set an attribute to each day cell inside day render function. Question: Can I get those attributes using date range? Is that doable? Any suggestions are much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the day cells has the class `fc-day`, and each of them has a property `data-date` showing the date it represents (e.g. `2017-09-19`).

So for example, let's say you are in a month view showing September 2017, and a custom attribute called "MyCustomAttr" (showing what day of the whole year that day is) has been added to those date cells via `dayRender`, like this:

```
dayRender: function(date, cell) {
  cell.attr("MyCustomAttr", "Day Of Year: " + date.format("DDD"));
},
```

Then, you want to get the custom attribute values of all the cells in the range 10th-15th September (exclusive), you can run this code (as long as it runs at some time after the dayRender callback was executed):

```
var days = $(".fc-day");
var attributes = [];
var rangeStart = moment("2017-09-10");
var rangeEnd = moment("2017-09-15");

days.each(function(index, element) {
  var day = moment($(this).data("date"));
  if (day.isBetween(rangeStart, rangeEnd)) 
  {
    attributes.push($(this).attr("MyCustomAttr"));
  }
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(attributes));
```

You can see a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/20/

N.B. I have just put the attribute values into an array as an example, which isn't very useful in itself, since they aren't associated with the days anymore. You didn't say what you wanted to do with the attributes once you've got them, so I'll leave it to you to modify the example to suit your needs.